# Filter methods for feature selection are often univariate. What multivariate filter methods exist, and what are their dis/advantages?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multivariate-analysis, feature-selection, univariate

Feature selection approaches are often grouped into three categories: "filter", "wrapper" and "embedded" approaches. Filter methods tend to assess the inclusion of an attribute based on some scoring metric, rather than *in-situ*. This has the advantage of being relatively computationally inexpensive, and easily human-interpretable.

Filter methods are often univariate, considering each attribute individually - for example by its mutual information or ANOVA f-score with the label. This has the disadvantage of not taking into account the interaction between features.

Do any **multivariate filter methods** exist, that take the interaction of features into account? If so - they would appear to have the advantages of filter methods, without the disadvantage. Are there any other pros or cons for them?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "multivariate filter methods"? Methods like LASSO are essentially multivariate, but do not check for interactions. If you are interested in finding interactions, like gene-gene interactions in genomics, this would be different.